# Ошибка в боте discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Мой discord-bot при запуске выдаёт ошибку, помогите пожалуйста ёё исправить.
Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'token' #тут я пишу настоящий токен, просто скрыл чтобы вы не узнали его
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)  # разрешаем передавать агрументы
async def say(ctx, arg):  # создаем асинхронную фунцию бота
    await ctx.send(arg)  # отправляем обратно аргумент

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1017, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1002, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 916, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 485, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 517, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('162.159.136.232', 443)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/discordt.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot.run(TOKEN)
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 678, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 658, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 472, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 288, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/NeDoProgrammist/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 943, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('162.159.136.232', 443)]
```

Comment: Чем помочь? У вас ошибка не в коде. У вас нет соединения с сервером Discord

Comment: А как исправить её?

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/11364/

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

вместо TOKEN введи свой токен

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

На момент ошибки, у вас как я понял было плохое интернет соединение, поэтому python не смог подключиться к боту. Попробуйте еще раз, но убедившись в том что интернет соединение - в порядке

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, которую вы получили, говорит о том, что ваш бот не может установить соединение с `Discord`. Это может быть вызвано несколькими вещами:

- Неправильный токен: Убедитесь, что вы используете правильный токен для вашего бота.
- Недоступность сервера `Discord`: Убедитесь, что `Discord` работает и доступен.
- Проблемы с интернет-соединением: Убедитесь, что у вас есть стабильное интернет-соединение.
- Неправильная версия python: Убедитесь, что вы используете поддерживаемую версию `Python`.